# Executing Stored Procedure Parallel way

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

As title, how to executed stored procedure in paralleled way?

In more detail,I have a Stored Procedure Created in Sql Server call Execute_Sql and Pass in one Parameter AreaID INT as a argument.

I called and executed successfully from .net C# by passing in one ID at a time with looping the ID to get the New_ID.

Here my problem, I am trying to do a paralleled way of executing the stored prod. Such as when i executing ID=1 ,In the mean time, I also executed ID=2 at the same time.

Whats Came on my mind in thread that created a paralleled way of processing.Is there any way of doing it on executing stored prod?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a new stored procedure that takes several `AreaID`s and then do all the processing at once on the SQL server.

Comment: @CoryLarson  agreed with you but there can be a situation we need to show the progress of processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate `sp_start_job`

You can't pass parameters into jobs however so you'd need to get your parameters in via another means.

You'd could set up the job so that it reads parameters from a table, and populate the table with the values you want to run the sproc against, and then fire off a number of calls to the job.

You'd probably want your job to mark which row it's working on by updating a bit flag or something on the row to prevent duplication of effort between jobs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it would be helpful if you posted your code. Quite often SQL can be modified to process multiple values in a "Set-based" way. In other words, if you had a set of values to process, you could process them all simultaneously.

There are many ways to accomplish this. You could pass in a delimited string and then parse that in your proc. Lots of ideas on the implementation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

You could also pass in XML and "join" to the XML in your proc using `APPLY`.

In SQL 2008+ you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Because I don't know what exactly you're doing with the AreaID parameter, I don't know if I've answered your question so here is some more info.

If you want to run a stored procedure asynchronously, your best bet is Service Broker which will allow you to put a parameter in a queue and separate thread(s) will process the queue. SQL manages all the ordering, locking, retry, spawning/killing threads etc. It's a very robust system.

There is a comment on the question from a different user who seems to be connected to the OP concerning progress tracking. Here is a thought:

You have a "queue" table that contains a batchid and the areaID parameter and a status flag.

```
CREATE TABLE asynchQueue
(
    RecNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    BatchID INT,
    AreaID INT,
    Status TINYINT
)
```

Your C# app inserts into the queue table with a unique batch id for your app and call (to group your requests)

You have a proc scheduled to run periodically like this:

```
CREATE PROC ProcessQueue
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @RecNo INT,
            @AreaId INT

    BEGIN TRAN
        SELECT TOP 1 @RecNo = recNo,
               @AreaID = areaId 
        FROM AsynchQueue WITH ROWLOCK, XLOCK
        WHERE Status = 0 

        UPDATE AsynchQueue SET Status = 1  --Mark record as in progress
         WHERE RecNo = @RecNo
    COMMIT 

    EXEC YourProc @AreaId

    UPDATE AsynchQueue SET Status = 2 -- Mark Record as complete
         WHERE RecNo = @RecNo         

 END
```

Or the proc could contain a loop to process all records in the table. The proc could be scheduled or invoked on demand using sp_start_job as John Weldon suggested.

You could then query status as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Status, 0))/COUNT(*) as PctComplete --in progress or complete div by total
FROM AsynchQueue WITH NOLOCK
WHERE BatchID = @yourBatchId
```

That query will give you the percent complete of your batch.